# Iterative Ids in Meteor Blaze

Tags: meteor, iteration, meteor-blaze

Really need help with this. If I am iterating using

```
{{#each items}}

<li id={{some_blaze_tag}}></li>

{{/each}}
```

How do I get this result?

```
<li id="1">item 1</li>
<li id="2">item 2</li>
<li id="3">item 3</li>
```

I'm pretty sure Ruby has an equivalent, and I can't seem to do the same in Meteor.

Help would be really appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blaze also has this support. within your `#each` loop , you have `@index` access which is an incremental counter basically.

```
<li id={{@index}}>Item {{@index}}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Out of interest, where can I find more in-depth information about Blaze?